# npm Fails to Install over Socks5 Proxy

Tags: node.js, git, proxy, npm, socks

I am having trouble running `npm install` over a socks5 proxy.

Proxy is running locally, to tunnel http(s) over ssh to company intranet: `ssh -vvv -D 5000 -N <SERVER_IP>`

I have configured npm's proxy:

```
npm config set proxy socks5h://localhost:5000
npm config set https-proxy=socks5h://localhost:5000
```

I just get:

```
npm ERR! git clone https://<INTRANET>/repo fatal: unable to access 'https://<INTRANET>/repo/': Could not resolve host: <INTRANET>
```

Any ideas?

P.S.: git clone from the same git repo address works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as of now, npm does not support socks proxy: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6204

I now use ProxyCap.
http://www.proxycap.com
Works great. It will manage the ssh tunnel + socks proxy and route all traffic automatically (also for npm) through it.

Comment: How to use ProxyCap with socks? Make a route rule that npm use that rule?

Comment: I just created a Rule that Redirects all traffic through the proxy. That also works for npm. If you want npm to use intranet npm server, add e.g.: "registry=http://npm.yourintranet.com/
" to  ~/.npmrc

Answer (score 1):

[Proxifier](http://www.) works for me. Simply add a proxy and `npm install ...`

[image: proxifier].com/mac/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `polipo` to convert `sock5` proxy to `http` proxy, and it's super convenient if you're under Linux.

You can reference this page for further detail:

- [Convert Socks Proxy To Http Proxy: Using Polipo](http://www.codevoila.com/post/16/convert-socks-proxy-to-http-proxy-using-polipo)

Answer (score 1):

For a workaround that works on both `Linux` and `Windows`, you can use `http-proxy-to-socks`.

```
$ npm install -g http-proxy-to-socks
$ hpts -s 127.0.0.1:1080 -p 8080
```

Now you have you http proxy at port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

### Use [v2rayN](https://github.com/2dust/v2rayN/releases/tag/4.20) as client.

It will launch both `socks5` and `http` proxy.

Then you can use its `http` proxy for `npm` proxy and `socks5` for other proxy at same time.

```sh
// http for npm
npm config set http-proxy http://127.0.0.1:10809

// socks5 for git
git config --global http.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:10808
```

### v2raN UI Screen Shot

[image: v2raN]